# iOS nav bar with username

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

How do we handle showing a http posted username to a navigation bar title? Here is a method which successfully shows a username in a jpeg represented photo taken by people in a `UIScrollView*listview;`

```
-(id)initWithIndex:(int)i andData:(NSDictionary*)data {
self = [super init];
if (self !=nil) {
    //initialize
    self.tag = [[data objectForKey:@"IdPhoto"] intValue];
    int row = i/3;
    int col = i % 3;
    self.frame = CGRectMake(1.5*kPadding+col*(kThumbSide+kPadding), 1.5*kPadding+row*(kThumbSide+kPadding), kThumbSide, kThumbSide);
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    //add the photo caption
    UILabel* caption = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, kThumbSide-16, kThumbSide, 16)];
    caption.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    caption.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    caption.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    caption.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
    caption.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"@%@",[data objectForKey:@"username"]];
    [self addSubview: caption];
    //add touch event
    [self addTarget:delegate action:@selector(didSelectPhoto:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    //load the image
    API* api = [API sharedInstance];
    int IdPhoto = [[data objectForKey:@"IdPhoto"] intValue];
    NSURL* imageURL = [api urlForImageWithId:[NSNumber numberWithInt: IdPhoto] isThumb:YES];
    AFImageRequestOperation* imageOperation = [AFImageRequestOperation imageRequestOperationWithRequest: [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:imageURL] success:^(UIImage *image) {
        //create an image view, add it to the view
        UIImageView* thumbView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: image];
        thumbView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,90,90);
        thumbView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        [self insertSubview: thumbView belowSubview: caption];
    }];
    NSOperationQueue* queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [queue addOperation:imageOperation];
}
return self;
}
```

Comment: `NSString* label` mmm, I think about big amount of refactoring, mmm

Comment: instead of making another label object you can use self.navigationItem.title.

Comment: Please include all the code inside of your `initWithIndex` method. You mentioned this code allows you details on slider. We need to see that the content works.

Answer (score 0):

Place the `self.navigationItem.title = label` in the same method as the `-(void)initWithIndex:(int)i andData:(NSDictionary*)data` method, after the label receives information.

```
-(void)initWithIndex:(int)i andData:(NSDictionary*)data {

    //remove the "@" from before the %@ that you have below

    label = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"@%@",[data objectForKey:@"username"]];

    self.navigationItem.title = label;
}
```

Depending on whether it needs to load immediately, you should call the `-(void)initWithIndex:(int)i andData:(NSDictionary*)data` in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` methods.

**UPDATE**

Try using this:

```
   [self.navigationItem setTitle: label];
```

For some reason this works better. I tried both in a test and this one worked for me over the other.

**UPDATE 2**

Initialise your label with a value/object.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

    label = @"";//initialises the value to be a blank string enabling use
    //call your method that assigns the title now.

}
```

Now when the method `-(void)initWithIndex:(int)i andData:(NSDictionary*)data` is called, the title should update as label has been initialised and will now update it's value.

**UPDATE 3 - AS PER ASKERS REQUEST**

At the top of .m file

```
@interface YourClassName ()
{
    NSString * label;
}

@end

@implementation YourClassName

-(void)viewDidLoad{

    label = @"";//initialises the value to be a blank string enabling use

}

-(void)initWithIndex:(int)i andData:(NSDictionary*)data {

    //remove the "@" from before the %@ that you have below

    label = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"@%@",[data objectForKey:@"username"]];
    //the label now has a new value so use it for title
    self.navigationItem.title = label;

    //test to see that there is a value available in log
    NSLog(@"What is the name: %@", label);
}
```

Comment: I added an alternative. I ran a test and the alternative worked for me. Hope it works for you

Comment: what is the ... after the init index method in view did load in the 3rd update?

Comment: You need to update your question if you want any further help. I need to see what's in this method because it is looking like you don't know how to use it correctly. That's not an insult it's an observation. Please show me the whole method :-)

Comment: ok this was the original method (update) it showed usernames on a custom caption on a jpeg image representation of a photo taken after a user logs in. It is updated above. its long and has irrelevant stuff but thanks for bearing with us.

Comment: When is that being called? It would appear that all you have to do is place the [self.navigation setTitle: label]; in with all of the other stuff, the same as you've done "caption.text" mate.

Comment: @user7221 Have you tried using [self.navigation setTitle: caption.text];?

Comment: @user7221 does it print anything in the log using NSLog (@"%@", label);